# How to print a qr code with brushes in PHP with GD?

Tags: php, gd, qr-code

I have a problem with drawing circles instead of cubes for displaying the qr code.

Here is my code for drawing cubes, I draw only one pixel after that I resize the image to the size I need it.

```
    ImageSetPixel($myImageRessource,$x,$y,$myColor);
```

After a little research I found a solution for drawing cirles with brushes

```
            $brush = imagecreatetruecolor(5,5);
            imagefilledellipse($brush,1,1,3,3,$myColor2);
            imagesetbrush($myImageRessource,$brush);
            ImageSetPixel($myImageRessource,$x,$y,$myColor);
```

Using brushes this way should draw a circle instead of a cube but it doesn't.

This is what it should look like

[image: This is what it should look like]

This is what I got

[image: This is what I got]

I don't see what wrong with this code.
Can somebody give me an advice please.

Comment: Added pictures of results

Comment: I've changed the headline to better fit to the thema

Answer (score 1):

You'll just have to use a bigger image. You can't really expect any program or code to draw a circle in a image that is only 2 by 2 pixels large.

Try something bigger, like having the image 5 by 5 pixels and using a radius of 2 or 3.

Also any reason why you don't directly draw circles on the final image? You should add an image to show us what you're trying to achieve.

---

Cause I've got some interest in QR codes, I've just written this sample rendering code:

```
<?php

$qr = // The actual QR code
    "1111111000011010001111111".
    "1000001001100010001000001".
    "1011101000001000101011101".
    "1011101010001100101011101".
    "1011101011000100101011101".
    "1000001000011110001000001".
    "1111111010101010101111111".
    "0000000000110011000000000".
    "1100011101010111100011000".
    "1010000111001001000111110".
    "0011111000100111101001011".
    "0000000101001010111101001".
    "0100111001011011101000001".
    "1101000110000101100100010".
    "1010111010011111001111011".
    "1010100001110011010010101".
    "1010111111111111111110100".
    "0000000011001001100010100".
    "1111111011010010101011001".
    "1000001010110011100010011".
    "1011101000011111111111100".
    "1011101001111111011101011".
    "1011101000100110100100101".
    "1000001010100010100110001".
    "1111111011101000100001001";

$size = 25; // Dimension in dots
$dot = 9; // Pixels per dot

$img = imagecreatetruecolor($size * $dot, $size * $dot);

// Enable alpha blending
imagealphablending($img, true);
imagesavealpha($img, true);

// Allocate colors
$back = imagecolorallocatealpha($img, 0, 0, 0, 127);
$dots = imagecolorallocatealpha($img, 0, 64, 127, 64);

// Fill the image with background/transparency
imagefill($img, 0, 0, $back);

// Loop over all dots and draw them:
for ($y = 0, $i = 0; $y < $size; $y++) {
    for ($x = 0; $x < $size; $x++, $i++) {
        if ($qr[$i] == '1') { // Draw a dot?
            // Draw rectangles
            //imagefilledrectangle($img, $x * $dot, $y * $dot, ($x + 1) * $dot - 1, ($y + 1) * $dot - 1, $dots);

            // Draw circles
            imagefilledellipse($img, ($x + .5) * $dot), ($y + .5) * $dot, $dot - 1, $dot - 1, $dots);

            // Draw a second set of circles for more aliased dots
            imagefilledellipse($img, ($x + .5) * $dot, ($y + .5) * $dot, $dot - 2, $dot - 2, $dots);
        }
    }
}

// Save the result
imagepng($img, "qr.png");
?>
```

This will result in the following image:

[image: Example QR code pointing to stackoverflow.com]

Comment: This is not working, it seems that the ImageSetPixel function ignores the brush I've setuped before.

Comment: That's because you're essentially rendering rectangles (your ellipses are too small to be noticeable as such). I've added some example code you may use free of charge, if it helps you.

Comment: Also, by using `imagesetpixel()` you essentially just manipulate single pixels. Single pixels are always in rectangle shape.

Comment: okey that makes sense but I like to use the brush function for painting so I can use every image I like to. The brush is ignored!

Comment: So you'd like to draw images as dots?

Answer (score 0):

A circle of 1 pixel wide, 1 pixel high is just one pixel, and pixels are square. If you want dots try to draw the image at least the size you want it to be displayed and then scale down.

Comment: This is not working, it seems that the ImageSetPixel function ignores the brush I've setuped before. –